# Do I need Tomcat Server for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am using Eclipse with Google App Engine Development Server right now on Win-7 platform . I have to create a simple website using Java . I am confused that do I need Tomcat Server installed in-order to develop Java based site using Eclipse Framework ?  Can Tomcat be installed on Win-7 platform ? please guide on this . If any better framework is available please suggest (as I am new to this) .

Comment: App Engine uses Jetty for its Java dev server. Why do you think you need Tomcat?

Comment: Yes, you can install Tomcat on Windows 7.  You can also integrate it with your Eclipse development environment by adding a server runtime.

Comment: *"Can Tomcat be installed on Win-7 platform ?"* Tomcat is written in Java. Java is platform independent. Just download and extract the zip. That's it.

Comment: Sorry forgot that Tomcat is platform independent and coded in Java , actually I am attending Java after 10 long years. Thanks for reminding  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GAE development server is specifically designed to help you develop applications for Google App Engine by simulating the actual GAE environment. If you plan to deploy the webapp on GAE, then it's all you need.

If you want to develop a standard Java EE webapp, then you indeed need a standard Java EE web container. Tomcat is one of them, but you could also use Jetty, GlassFish, JBooss, Resin or any other Java EE web container. And since they're all written in Java, they're all multiplatform and can all be installed on Windows.

Also Eclipse is not a framework. It's an IDE. Developing a webapp using Eclipse, IntelliJ, NetBeans or a text editor and the JDK doesn't change anything to the webapp. They're just tools to help you write Java code.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance will do the same. Please suggest Eclipse is better or NetBeans for website development ?

Comment: It's a matter of taste. Some prefer NetBeans and some prefer Eclipse.

Comment: Do I need GlassFish installed too and integarted with Eclipse for web development ?

Comment: Have you read my answer? Glassfish is just another Java EE container. If you want to deploy your app on GAE, use the GAE development server. If you plan to deploy it on Glassfish, then use Glassfish. If you plan to deploy it on Tomcat, then use Tomcat. Why would you need to have Glassfish if you don't plan to use it?